# Connecting Grafana to MySQL show query failed, why?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, grafana, mysql-connector, grafana-variable

I'm trying to connect Grafana with MySQL.

I pulled grafana to docker and ran it. MySQL is not in container.

I created user with all privileges, created database and table. Set from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.

When i trying to connect to MySQL in Grafana, it show

```
query failed - please inspect Grafana server log for details
```

I don't know what to do, could someone help?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: When I spam "save&test", it showed

```
Datasource has already been updated by someone else. Please reload and try again
```

Answer (score 2):

So after all it work this.
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/

U need to create user with permissions only for select.

```
 CREATE USER 'grafanaReader' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
 GRANT SELECT ON mydatabase.mytable TO 'grafanaReader';
```